# Kotlin Coroutines vs CompletableFuture

Tags: java, kotlin, concurrency, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

Can anybody explain me why people should use coroutines? Is there some coroutine code example which shows better completion time against regular java concurrent code *(without magical delay() function, nobody uses `delay()` in production)* ?

In my personal example coroutines(line 1) are suck against java code(line 2). Maybe i did something wrong?

Example:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.time.Instant
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture
import java.util.concurrent.Future

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
fun main() = runBlocking {
    val begin = Instant.now().toEpochMilli()
    val jobs = List(150_000) {
        GlobalScope.launch { print(getText().await()) } // :1
//        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync { "." }.thenAccept { print(it) } // :2
    }
    jobs.forEach { it.join() }
    println(Instant.now().toEpochMilli() - begin)
}

fun getText(): Future<String> {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync {
        "."
    }
}

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
suspend fun <T> Future<T>.await(): T = suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
    cont.resume(this.get()) {
        this.cancel(true)
    }
}
```

Additional question:

Why i should create this coroutine wrapper `await()`? It seems does not improve coroutine version of code otherwise `get()` method complains on `inappropriate blocking method call`?

Comment: `delay()` is actually an excellent approximation of production code because a coroutine gets suspended while doing nothing but wait for the response to arrive. Here's a nice summary: use threads to parallelize work, use coroutines to parallelize waiting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The goal of coroutines is not "better completion time."  The goal -- at which it succeeds quite well, honestly -- is that coroutines are *easier to use*.

That said, what you've done in your code is not *at all* a good way to compare the speed of two alternate approaches.  Comparing the speed of things in Java and getting realistic results is *extremely hard*, and you should read [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/869736) at a minimum before attempting it.  The way you are currently attempting to compare two pieces of Java code will *lie to you* about the realistic performance behavior of your code.

To answer your additional question, the answer is that you *should not* create that `await` method.  You should not use `get()` -- or `java.util.concurrent.Future` -- with coroutine code, whether it's in `suspendCancellableCoroutine` or otherwise.  If you want to use a `CompletableFuture`, use [the provided library](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8) to interact with it from coroutine code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added this library in my sample and got much better result, but still worse than Java. Now i've understood purpose of this wrappers. My wrapper was not really suspendable.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a cleaned-up version of your code that I used for benchmarking. Note I removed `print` from the measured code because printing itself is a heavyweight operation, involving mutexes, JNI, blocking output streams, etc. Instead I update a volatile variable.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.future.await
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import java.lang.Thread.sleep
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS

@Volatile
var total = 0

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
fun main() = runBlocking {
    println("Warmup")
    measure(20_000)
    println("Measure")
    val begin = System.nanoTime()
    measure(40_000)
    println("Completed in ${NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - begin)} ms")
}

fun getText(): CompletableFuture<Int> {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync {
        sleep(1)
        1
    }
}

suspend fun measure(count: Int) {
    val jobs = List(count) {
        GlobalScope.launch { total += getText().await() } // :1
//        getText().thenAccept { total += it } // :2
    }
    jobs.forEach { it.join() }
}
```

My result is 6.5 seconds for case number one vs. 7 seconds for case number two. That's a 7% difference and it's probably very specific to this exact scenario, not something you'll generally see as a difference between the two approaches.

The reason to choose coroutines over `CompletionStage`-based programming is definitely not about those 7%, but about the massive difference in convenience. To see what I mean, I invite you to rewrite the `main` function by calling just `computeAsync`, without using `future.await()`:

```
suspend fun main() {
    try {
        if (compute(1) == 2) {
            println(compute(4))
        } else {
            println(compute(7))
        }
    } catch (e: RuntimeException) {
        println("Got an error")
        println(compute(8))
    }
}

fun main_no_coroutines() {
    // Let's see how it might look!
}

fun computeAsync(input: Int): CompletableFuture<Int> {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync {
        sleep(1)
        if (input == 7) {
            throw RuntimeException("Input was 7")
        }
        input % 3
    }
}

suspend fun compute(input: Int) = computeAsync(input).await()
```

Comment: Regarding your second code section, I don't quite get this. There is no parallelism: it takes >= 3ms to run (for better visibility, make it `sleep(1000)` and then it takes 3 seconds). I got the same results using `main_no_coroutines()` by copying `main()` and replacing `compute()` with `computeAsync().get()` and `RuntimeException` with `Exception` (because it may be `ExecutionException`). The readability and ease of use of `main_no_coroutines` is about the same, so I don't see the advantage of using the coroutines version.

Comment: There is indeed no parallelism in the 2nd code section, which is about the choice of programming paradigm for non-blocking code. I present simple-looking sequential, non-blocking code, and challenge the reader to rewrite it using the async programming style that keeps the non-blocking nature. `Future.get()` is a blocking function.

Answer (score 2):

After switching to this [kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8) library and adding sleep(1) to my `getText()` function

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.future.await
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import java.lang.Thread.sleep
import java.time.Instant
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val begin = Instant.now().toEpochMilli()
    val jobs = List(150_000) {
        GlobalScope.launch { print(getText().await()) } // :1
//        getText().thenAccept { print(it) } // :2
    }
    jobs.forEach { it.join() }
    println(Instant.now().toEpochMilli() - begin)
}

fun getText(): CompletableFuture<String> {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync {
        sleep(1)
        "."
    }
}
```

i made coroutine version faster than java version!!! Apparently this additional coroutine layer becomes justified when there is some delay.

Comment: If you intend to block the thread like `sleep` does, then don't look into coroutines. They won't provide you much value over `Future.get()`.

Comment: But in my example I've got much better result than with CompletableFuture. It seems sleep works good with coroutines. Looks like java does not block it. [kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8 library](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8/test/examples/simple-example-1.kt) has similar example

Comment: I really wonder what you actually want to achieve. I also wonder what exactly code you are using that gives a much better result. In my experience, that `sleep(1)` is the dominant bottleneck and the rest doesn't matter. Furthermore, `CompletableFuture.await()` is nothing but a thin wrapper on the underlying Java mechanism, so it can hardly become faster than it.

Comment: Just want to figure out how this coroutines work. I added code which i'm testing.

Comment: I'm testing line 1 against line 2.

Comment: But you also made some changes, so I don't know what exactly you're measuring. Also, you print from each job, but printing itself is a heavyweight operation that offsets the result. I made a benchmark based on your code and got pretty similar results, within 7% of each other.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 versions of `compute` method without rewriting methods signature. I think i've got your point. With coroutines we write complex parallel code in familiar sequential style. But coroutine `await` wrapper does not make this work due suspending technic, it just implement same logic that i did.

```
import java.lang.Thread.sleep
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture

fun main() {
    try {
        if (compute(1) == 2) {
            println(compute(4))
        } else {
            println(compute(7))
        }
    } catch (e: RuntimeException) {
        println("Got an error")
        println(compute(8))
    }
}

fun compute(input: Int): Int {
    var exception: Throwable? = null
    val supplyAsync = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync {
        sleep(1)
        if (input == 7) {
            throw RuntimeException("Input was 7")
        }
        input % 3
    }.exceptionally {
        exception = it
        throw it
    }
    while (supplyAsync.isDone.not()) {}
    return if (supplyAsync.isCompletedExceptionally) {
        throw exception!!
    } else supplyAsync.get()
}

fun compute2(input: Int): Int {
    try {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync {
            sleep(1)
            if (input == 7) {
                throw RuntimeException("Input was 7")
            }
            input % 3
        }.get()
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        throw ex.cause!!
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea was to remove `.await()` from `compute` so it returns a `CompletableFuture` and then try to rewrite the caller-side logic to have the same effect as mine. This moves a lot of logic into `compute()` which wasn't there originally.

Comment: And I don't understand your comment that it's not `.await()` that makes this work. It is precisely that method that converts your `CompletableFuture`-returning function into a result-returning function, allowing you to use the plain sequential idiom, including a big try-catch block that catches exceptions from any async invocation.

Comment: I wanted to say that this is not coroutine's merit  to make handle exceptions easier.

Comment: Yes, that's how I understood you, but it doesn't make sense to me since it's just the coroutines and nothing else that make it so much easier.